# Why does Multi Peer Connectivity only work with MCAdvertiserAssistant and not MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, bonjour, multipeer-connectivity

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/) on [MultiPeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328) (MCF) and list most tutorials online, they took the shortcut of using the services of [MCAdvertiserAssistant](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCAdvertiserAssistant_class/index.html) and [MCBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCBrowserViewController_class/index.html)

I tried implementing the same tutorial but with using [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserClassRef/index.html) and [MCNearbyServiceBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceBrowserClassRef/index.html) instead because i'm interested in customizing the discoverability on my app.

things work fine as far as listing the nearby devices.. but then the trouble starts in the `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate` where I call this method:

```
- (void)           advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser
 didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
                  withContext:(NSData *)context
            invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, MCSession *))invitationHandler {

    // Allow the peer to join this Vibereel
    MCSession *peerSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID];
    peerSession.delegate = self;
    invitationHandler(YES, peerSession);
    NSLog(@"Accepted entry request for peer %@", [peerID displayName]);
}
```

this does **not** trigger the [did change state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionDelegateRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MCSessionDelegate/session:peer:didChangeState:) method:

```
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state
```

although it did with the original versions.

I know I obviously need to put more code to demonstrate the problem.. and so I created a [github repo](https://github.com/abbood/MCDemo) that started with the original code. This is the [commit](https://github.com/abbood/MCDemo/commit/3af800ded048a41153fda0bb6199bdeb61debe1c) that adds the custom made browser along with the custom UITableViewController to display nearby devices (works fine) and here is the [commit](https://github.com/abbood/MCDemo/commit/db724a8f6f20c38089269c61dfab57a0c8d4e9ea) that does the advertising (**doesn't work**)

Comment: Can you post the code that you send the invitation with?

Comment: I faced same problem and finaly got rid off it by holding the session in an instance variable. Its wierd but it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the peerSession a property of the class instead of a local variable of the method. The problem is that in your code the peerSession is released at the end of the method. I have a working example on my [blog](http://peterfennema.nl/ios-multipeer-1/).

Comment: The `MCSession` instance is being passed to the invitationHandler block so it doesn't matter that it's being released within the method. I agree that the session should be a property, though. No reason to be creating a new one every time.

Comment: Peter's blog also points out is that with peers having both an advertiser and a browser, do NOT accept sessions in both directions, or the underlying code seems to get confused. He chose to compare a hash of the peerIDs in didReceiveInviation to decide which of the two should accept and which should reject.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts here after checking out code on you repo, I'm sure that this issue is mostly todo with the way how you've your `MCSession` object setup. I agree with Peter here, you should have one session object common across the flow as a strong reference.

Secondly, since you're trying to get things working with just `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` & `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`, you'd need to make sure the flow is rightly setup in general. Once you found a peer via the following callback,

`- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;`

invite the peer using `[browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:self.session withContext:nil timeout:0];` now at the peer end you'd receive a callback on the following delegate,

`- (void)          advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID 
                 withContext:(NSData *)context 
           invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session))invitationHandler`

and you accept the invitation by confirming to `invitationHandler(YES, session)` (as you doing it above), if you've your session object common across the flow, this should get `- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state` triggered with `MCSessionStateNotConnected` then `MCSessionStateConnecting` state. Now, on the first peer you will receive the following delegate callback

`-      (void)session:(MCSession *)session 
didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray *)certificate 
             fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID 
   certificateHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept))certificateHandler;`

and here you should be confirming via setting the `certificateHandler(YES)` to establish the connection. This is the last very important piece, specially when you're trying to get the whole thing working without the factory provided view controllers.

I know this isn't easy to get it working for the first time, but it gets easy along the way. Please mention me in comments, I'll reply you back for any clarification.